# JSF/ Styling h:outputText tooltip

Tags: html, css, jsf

I would like to create a custom look for a tooltip.

```
<h:outputText value="blarg" title="tooltip">
```

Plese do not tell me to use rich:tooltip as I have tried and they have a bug where it extends past a data table. So I was wondering if it is possible to actually style the jsf's outputText tooltip.

If you know how to, please give me pointers.

Thank you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot style a tooltip using plain vanilla HTML/CSS. You really need JavaScript for this as well which walks through the HTML DOM tree and "converts" every `title` attribute into some hidden fancy looking `<div>` which gets shown during `onmouseover`.

Since RichFaces already ships with jQuery, it should be possible to grab a jQuery plugin for that. For example, the [qTip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

> *Please do not tell me to use `<rich:tooltip>` as I have tried and they have a bug where it extends past a data table.*

It should technically be a matter of finetuning the CSS associated with the `<rich:tooltip>`.

Comment: hmm i've looked at most of the rich:tooltips, but there seems to be a bug in 3.3.3, I couldn't upgrade to 4.0 due to weblogic incompatibilites.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this.

Use `<p:tooltip/>` of Primefaces.

View:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
    <h:outputLink styleClass="outputText" id="fades" value="#">
       <h:outputText value="Your text"/>
    </h:outputLink>
    <p:tooltip id="toolTipFades" for="fades" value="The text for tooltip"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Css:

```
.outputText{
 cursor: default!important;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 }
```

With  this code you simulate a `<h:outputText />` with a tooltip and works ;D